# array with objects containing array

Tags: reactjs

Sorry guys if my way of asking the question in the title is not correct.
I am working on a project on react js and I am getting the data like this

```
[
    {
        "count": [
            {
                "1": 16
            },

            {
                "1": 149
            }

        ],
        "day": "2019-08-27"
    }
]
```

now this is my first time I am dealing with this kind of data and I really have no idea how can I show it like this I am really sorry guys I literally can't even show what I have tried because it does not seem relevant

```
[
    {
       count: 165
       day:"2019-08-27"
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up JSON Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data you're getting is under a variable called `data` you could use `reduce`:

The below makes the assumption the count is always an array of objects with just 1 key called `'1'`.

```
const newData = data.map(datum => {
  datum.count = datum.count.reduce((count, item) => {
    return count + item['1']
  }, 0)

  return datum
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
let arr = [
  // item
  {
    count: [
      {
        "1": 16
      },

      {
        "1": 149
      }
    ],
    day: "2019-08-27"
  }
];

arr.map(item => {
  Object.keys(item).map(key => {
    console.log(item[key])
    // if item[key] is iterable
    if(Array.isArray(item[key])) {
      item[key].map(val => {
        console.log(item)
      })
    } else {
      console.log(item[key])
    }
  });
});
```

The concept is that for Objects you do a `Object.keys().something` and for an array you do a `arr.map(item => ...)`